# Is anyone else having issues with opening app links on iOS6 iPad3?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6

Links to ios apps (to the app store) are not working for me on my iPad 3/iOS 6. I thought it was my code causing the problem initially, but then I tried it on an iPhone, and an older iPad 2 and they both worked. I looked into it further and it seems no links are working (that I can find). I have googled, but I have not found anything yet. Is there anyone else having this problem?

Example: [link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=gmail%20app%20for%20app%20store&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fus%2Fapp%2Fgmail%2Fid422689480%3Fmt%3D8&ei=8ll2UMShKMzPmAWOyoGQDA&usg=AFQjCNE_0fwN6m6iLhQYdqjVGxhmv8bS1w) - this link will work on my computer and phone, but not on my iPad3 running iOS6 - it will just bring up the app store app showing the main screen.

Does anyone know how to navigate to the app store with a specific app as the target? When I try, the app store just shows featured page.

---

**Update**: Thanks to the person who suggested using `https` instead of `http`, it seems to work for iOS6 and iOS5.

Comment: It looked like the same was happening on my iPad. But, what happens is the AppStore App is opened and then after some delay a small View containing the App details, in your case, Gmail, appears. But its really annoying as AppStore doesn't show any ActivityIndicator or anything.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @mayuur. But I tested it (waited for 5 min) and no small view with the gmail app came up... :(

Comment: this happened with me, so I shared it! Btw, does it happen with all the app links? It might be a bug then?!

Comment: @mayuur, no discouragement meant. I was just sharing my experience too ;). As I mentioned in my question, it is happening in all of the links I have tried, so it may be a bug, but I thought I would have been able to find some others complaining about it. I wonder if it has something to do with any current maintenance...

Comment: Someone commented in the bowls (not sure where, somewhere in a review or something) of this question that using https still works.